# 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: arrays, angular

I have seen this error reproduced online in different threads.

I have tried these and i am still not able to find a solution:

> (11,23): Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).

This is refering to the array below `pulses`:

```
export class Session {
  constructor(
   public objectId: string,
   public createdAt: string,
   public updatedAt: string,
   public ACL: string,
   public date: string,
   public pulses: Array<any> = [],
   public peripheral_id: string,
   public total_mg: number){}
}
```

Above is a simple Model to define a Session object returned in a Service GET request.

Why is this Array giving me an error and what would be a solution to solving this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is

```
public pulses: any[] = [];
```

And about the error, I guess it's because you should use `new Array(Type)` instead

Comment: I highly doubt that by replacing `Array<any>` with `any[]`, you still get the error. Or it's not the pulses property that is in error ! Another thing, try stopping and launching `ng serve` again, sometimes model changes aren't taken into consideration.

Comment: It was the ng serve that was causing the issue, im really glad you pointed that out because i had no clue that could be an issue.

Comment: Neither did I, now everytime I have a problem I relaunch the `ng serve`. Try thinking about it sometimes !